# how to restart hadoop cluster on emr

Tags: hadoop, emr

I have a hadoop installation on the Amazon Elastic MapReduce , whenever I try to restart the cluster I get the following error:

```
/stop-all.sh
no jobtracker to stop
The authenticity of host 'localhost (::1)' can't be established. RSA key fingerprint is
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes 
localhost: Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
localhost: Permission denied (publickey).
no namenode to stop
localhost: Permission denied (publickey).
localhost: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Any idea on how to restart hadoop?

Comment: where is the `stop-all.sh` (and others) located?

Answer (score 2):

Following hack worked for me.

I have replaced "ssh" command in sbin/slaves.sh & sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh with "ssh -i ~/.ssh/keyname"

Answer (score 1):

I'm using hadoop version 2.4 and this worked for me:

```
export HADOOP_SSH_OPTS="-i /home/hadoop/mykey.pem"
```

Comment: This resolved the error for me reported in this case...and seems superior to the other suggestion.  That said, the script doesn't work for me (nor do the stop-dfs or stop-yarn scripts):  

[sbin]$ ./stop-all.sh 
This script is Deprecated. Instead use stop-dfs.sh and stop-yarn.sh
Stopping namenodes on [ip-10-169-233-108.ec2.internal]
ip-10-169-233-108.ec2.internal: no namenode to stop
localhost: no datanode to stop
Stopping secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: no secondarynamenode to stop
stopping yarn daemons
no resourcemanager to stop
localhost: no nodemanager to stop
no proxyserver to stop

Answer (score 0):

For the stop-all.sh script to work, you probably need to have the same user in all the machines as the user with which you are executing the stop-all.sh script.

Moreover, it seems you do not have a password less ssh setup from the machine you are executing stop-all.sh to rest of the machines that will spare you from manually entering the password for each machine separately. Passwords might be different for the same user for different machines, please don't forget that.