# Do I need to reload yarn when I edit yarn-site.xml?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I've edited `yarn-site.xml` on my cluster. Specifically I've edited the `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb` setting.

Do I need to reload the config somehow, or restart the resource manager or something for this to take effect, or are these config files watched and reloaded automatically?

Comment: The short answer is yes, it needs reloaded. Might need to restart the node manager as well.

Comment: That depends on how you installed hadoop. If you are using a Hortonworks installation, you could use Ambari, or from a terminal this link should help - http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.4/bk_installing_manually_book/content/start_yarn.html

Comment: This is on EMR. No Ambari as far as I know.

Comment: Hmm. Never used EMR. How was YARN started or was it just running when you started the cluster? Is there any disadvantage to rebooting the cluster?

Comment: Hadoop 2.6 gets installed automatically. I don't know how to reboot the cluster either, but yeah, definitely an option since this cluster is only used for a single job. How would I do that?

Comment: Well, [Answer 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32207723/how-to-restart-hdfs-on-amazon-emr) (expect this is for HDFS),  [Answer 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813958/how-to-restart-hadoop-cluster-on-emr) (which is the whole cluster), or [Answer 3](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=373569) (Amazon forum),

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have.

You can also verify this by using Ambari. One edit in the yarn-site.xml file triggers some services to be restarted. YARN is one of them

Comment: This is assuming Ambari is installed